# Analog of setShapesVisible

Tags: java, jfreechart

Hi I need to make dots on my chart visible but setShapesVisiable method now is Deprecated. 
May be someone know analog of this method.

Comment: setShapesVisible is a method of what class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ou I find answer))

we need to use setSeriesShapesVisible method.